# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SVGFPPL PONDY' to data type int in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query I am passing 2 parameters but hitting this error

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SVGFPPL PONDY'
>   to data type int."

Please help me to overcome this issue..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[Product]   
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here  
 @i_LocationID Varchar(50),  
 @i_ProductTypeID Varchar(50)='0'  
AS  
BEGIN  
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.  
 SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    -- Insert statements for procedure here  
  --/************  Get Purchase Product based on location*************\-- 





     SELECT  P.ProductID, P.ProductName FROM Product P          
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LocationProductMap LPM ON LPM.ProductID = P.ProductID          
     WHERE  LocationID =@i_LocationID  AND (@i_ProductTypeID ='0' OR P.ProductType =  @i_ProductTypeID

     --/************   Product based on location*************\--   

      SELECT P.ProductID,P.ProductName FROM Product P          
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LocationProductMap LPM ON LPM.ProductID = P.ProductID        
     WHERE LocationID=@i_LocationID AND LPM.ProductInFlow = 2  AND  (@i_ProductTypeID ='0' OR P.ProductType=@i_ProductTypeID)  
END
```

Comment: The question is rather why you are trying to compare varchar data with integer data?

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening because either, or both of `LocationProductMap.LocationID` or `Product.ProductType` are integer columns, whereas you are trying to compare them to `VARCHAR` parameters passed into your `PROC`. The following MVCE demonstrates this:

```
CREATE Table dbo.Foo
(ID INT);
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.FindFoo
    @i_Foo VARCHAR(50)
AS
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Foo Where ID = @i_Foo
GO

EXEC FindFoo 'bar'
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FindFoo, Line 19
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'bar' to data type int.

The solution is to adjust your parameters so that they match the types of the columns. I would suggest using NULL (and not '0') to represent an optional filter on the query. Also, aren't you missing a `UNION` of the two queries? Otherwise your proc will return two resultsets - i.e. your PROC might look like:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.FindStuff
    @i_FooID INT,
    @i_BarID INT
AS
    SELECT Foo.ID, Foo.Name FROM dbo.Foo WHERE @i_FooID IS NULL OR Foo.ID = @i_FooID

    UNION

    SELECT Bar.ID, Bar.Name FROM dbo.Bar Where @i_BarID IS NULL OR Bar.ID = @i_BarID
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
WHERE  convert(varchar(50),LocationID) = @i_LocationID  
AND 
(@i_ProductTypeID ='0' OR convert(varchar(50),P.ProductType) =  @i_ProductTypeID
...
 WHERE convert(varchar(50),LocationID)=@i_LocationID 
 AND 
 LPM.ProductInFlow = 2  
 AND  (@i_ProductTypeID ='0' OR convert(varchar(50),P.ProductType)=@i_ProductTypeID)
```